# How do I cap a T junction on a roof ridge?

Tags: roofing

My house's roof-ridge joins a small barn at the center of the barn's roof-ridge forming a "T".  The barn does not have a vent cap.  Metal flashing was used on both valleys where the house roof meets the barn and the flashing runs all the way to the junction of the T.  I have just reshingled the barn and am at the point of capping the ridge.  Can anyone tell me how to install the cap at the junction point where the cross of the T meets the stem?

Answer (score 1):

The lower roof shingles are capped by upper roof.

[image]